# nuxt.js auth-next module: LoginWith is not responding although there is no error

Tags: express, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

#### Version

module: 5.0.0
nuxt: 6.14.4

#### Nuxt configuration

[mode](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode):

- [mode ] universal

#### Nuxt configuration

```
auth: {
      strategies: {
        local: {
          token: {
            property: 'token',
            // required: true,
            // type: 'Bearer'
          },
          user: {
            property: 'user',
            // autoFetch: true
          },
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', method: 'post' },
            logout: { url: process.env.baseUrl + '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: process.env.baseUrl + '/auth/user', method: 'get' }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

### Reproduction

> :warning: without a minimal reproduction we won't be able to look into your issue

What is expected?

I installed the auth-next module. I'm working on making login with loginWith.

`let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: form }) console.log(response)`

What is actually happening?

When the request is sent, there is no response, although there was no error.
and I can't login to the server for a long time. "localhost: 3000". The browser has been trying to login for a long time and I am getting the error I wrote below.

api/index.js:

```
`const refreshTokens = {}

app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {


  const { username, password } = req.body
  const valid = username.length && password === '123'
  const expiresIn = 15
  const refreshToken =
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000000000000 - 1 + 1)) + 1

  if (!valid) {
    throw new Error('Invalid username or password')
  }

  const accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(
    {
      username,
      picture: 'https://github.com/nuxt.png',
      name: 'User ' + username,
      scope: ['test', 'user']
    },
    'dummy',
    {
      expiresIn
    }
  )

  refreshTokens[refreshToken] = {
    accessToken,
    user: {
      username,
      picture: 'https://github.com/nuxt.png',
      name: 'User ' + username
    }
  }
console.log("burda")
  res.json({
    token: {
      accessToken,
      refreshToken
    }
  })
})`
```

error:

```
                                                                                                                                                     12:50:41

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1032:000001BBBC1CA4A0]   414463 ms: Mark-sweep 1983.7 (2051.9) -> 1976.2 (2053.2) MB, 4949.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.128, current mu = 0.018) deserialize GC in old space requested
[1032:000001BBBC1CA4A0]   418229 ms: Mark-sweep 1977.1 (2053.2) -> 1976.6 (2054.2) MB, 3699.0 / 0.2 ms  (average mu = 0.079, current mu = 0.018) allocation failure GC in old space requested        


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x030358c06c61 <Object map = 000002697006D119>
    0: builtin exit frame: defineProperty(this=0x0104219f1dd1 <Object map = 000002E47D4AC219>,0x01ac32fcde51 <Object map = 0000011B963D19B9>,0x01ac32fcde31 <String[17]: RegExpLeftContext>,0x01ac32fc8769 <Object map = 0000009FECFED5C9>,0x0104219f1dd1 <Object map = 000002E47D4AC219>)

    1: copyPropsRenamed(aka copyPropsRenamed) [000001AC32FC9059] [internal/per_context/primor...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210101.125635.1032.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 00007FF740FCCF2F napi_wrap+112799
 2: 00007FF740F6CF26 public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+55702
 3: 00007FF740F6DDB3 public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+59427
 4: 00007FF74178A27E private: void __cdecl v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached(void) __ptr64+94
 5: 00007FF741772351 public: class v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Contents __cdecl v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize(void) __ptr64+833
 6: 00007FF74163E8AC public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64)+1436
 7: 00007FF741649AE0 public: void __cdecl v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks(void) __ptr64+1312
 8: 00007FF741646604 public: static bool __cdecl v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent(class v8::internal::HeapObject)+3204
 9: 00007FF74163BE03 public: bool __cdecl v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(enum v8::internal::AllocationSpace,enum v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason,enum v8::GCCallbackFlags) __ptr64+1283
10: 00007FF74163A474 public: void __cdecl v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap(class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Map>) __ptr64+2452
11: 00007FF74165B7BB private: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::FixedArray> __cdecl v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(enum v8::internal::RootIndex,int,class v8::internal::Object,enum v8::internal::AllocationType) __ptr64+107
12: 00007FF741654787 public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::String> __cdecl v8::internal::Factory::InternalizeString<unsigned short>(class v8::internal::Vector<unsigned short const 
> const & __ptr64,bool) __ptr64+471
13: 00007FF7414A3209 public: static class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary> __cdecl v8::internal::HashTable<class v8::internal::NameDictionary,class v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary>,int,enum v8::internal::AllocationType)+233
14: 00007FF74149A05D public: static class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary> __cdecl v8::internal::Dictionary<class v8::internal::NameDictionary,class v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Name>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::PropertyDetails,int * __ptr64)+109
15: 00007FF741499E76 public: static class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary> __cdecl v8::internal::BaseNameDictionary<class v8::internal::NameDictionary,class v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::NameDictionary>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Name>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::PropertyDetails,int * __ptr64)+118
16: 00007FF7414EC829 public: void __cdecl v8::internal::JSReceiver::SetIdentityHash(int) __ptr64+4217
17: 00007FF7414CDE66 public: void __cdecl v8::internal::LookupIterator::TransitionToAccessorPair(class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,enum v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) __ptr64+598
18: 00007FF7414CE1D5 public: void __cdecl v8::internal::LookupIterator::TransitionToAccessorProperty(class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,enum v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) __ptr64+789
19: 00007FF7414DE4EA public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::JSObject::AddProperty(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::JSObject>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Name>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,enum v8::internal::PropertyAttributes)+4794
20: 00007FF7414EF2D1 public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::JSObject::TransitionElementsKind(class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::JSObject>,enum v8::internal::ElementsKind)+2497
21: 00007FF7414EA802 public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::JSObject::NormalizeProperties(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::JSObject>,enum v8::internal::PropertyNormalizationMode,int,char const * __ptr64)+1778
22: 00007FF7414DE643 public: static class v8::internal::MaybeHandle<class v8::internal::Object> __cdecl v8::internal::JSObject::DefineAccessor(class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::JSObjc 
t>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Name>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,enum v8::internal::PropertyAttributes)+307
23: 00007FF7416FCA81 public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+56049
24: 00007FF7416FD8FE public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+59758
25: 00007FF741BD740D public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+546893
26: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
27: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
28: 00007FF741BE94FC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+620860
29: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
30: 00007FF741B597F1 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+31793
31: 00007FF741B593DC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+30748
32: 00007FF741697F63 public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code>,unsigned __int64,class 
v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,unsigned __int64)+1395
33: 00007FF7416978E6 public: static class v8::internal::MaybeHandle<class v8::internal::Object> __cdecl v8::internal::Execution::Call(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,int,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object> * __ptr64 const)+182
34: 00007FF74176895D public: class v8::MaybeLocal<class v8::Value> __cdecl v8::Function::Call(class v8::Local<class v8::Context>,class v8::Local<class v8::Value>,int,class v8::Local<class v8::Value> * __ptr64 const) __ptr64+605
35: 00007FF740FEB190 bool __cdecl node::InitializeContext(class v8::Local<class v8::Context>)+864
36: 00007FF740FEB4B9 class v8::Local<class v8::Context> __cdecl node::NewContext(class v8::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::Local<class v8::ObjectTemplate>)+89
37: 00007FF740F76241 public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+93361
38: 00007FF740F7768B public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+98555
39: 00007FF74173DF10 public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+323456
40: 00007FF74173D457 public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+320711
41: 00007FF74173D798 public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+321544
42: 00007FF74173D59E public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code> __cdecl v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle(int) __ptr64+321038
43: 00007FF741BD740D public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+546893
44: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
45: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
46: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
47: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
48: 00007FF741BAA486 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+362694
49: 00007FF741B57973 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+23987
50: 00007FF741C3BAF0 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+958256
51: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
52: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
53: 00007FF741B5C2BC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+42748
54: 00007FF741B86F63 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+218019
55: 00007FF741BAB8C2 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+367874
56: 00007FF741B7945D public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+161949
57: 00007FF741B596DC public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+31516
58: 00007FF741697FF0 public: static void __cdecl v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Code>,unsigned __int64,class 
v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,unsigned __int64)+1536
v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,unsigned __int64)+1779
60: 00007FF7416984C2 public: static class v8::internal::MaybeHandle<class v8::internal::Object> __cdecl v8::internal::Execution::TryCall(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object>,int,class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::Object> * __ptr64 const,enum v8::internal::Execution::MessageHandling,class v8::internal::MaybeHandle<class v8::internal::Object> * __ptr64)+354
61: 00007FF74167A4D5 public: int __cdecl v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks(class v8::internal::Isolate * __ptr64) __ptr64+501
62: 00007FF740FECE35 public: __cdecl node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope(void) __ptr64+597
63: 00007FF740FED1A4 public: __cdecl node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope(void) __ptr64+1476
64: 00007FF740FE6E73 public: int __cdecl v8::internal::compiler::Operator::EffectOutputCount(void)const __ptr64+179
66: 00007FF740F5B8F7 public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<class v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::NumberOfBucketsOffset(void)+61383
67: 00007FF74101D417 uv_timer_stop+775
68: 00007FF741019ECB uv_async_send+331
69: 00007FF74101966C uv_loop_init+1212
70: 00007FF741019834 uv_run+244
71: 00007FF740F29681 private: class v8::internal::SourcePositionTableBuilder * __ptr64 __cdecl v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayWriter::source_position_table_builder(void) __ptr64+31713     
72: 00007FF740F96223 int __cdecl node::Start(int,char * __ptr64 * __ptr64 const)+275
73: 00007FF740E16A9C RC4_options+340380
74: 00007FF741C8F3F8 public: virtual bool __cdecl v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(class v8::internal::Heap * __ptr64) __ptr64+1300536
75: 00007FFB33797034 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
76: 00007FFB3531D0D1 RtlUserThreadStart+33
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! illiyun@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the illiyun@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-01T09_56_40_326Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with fresh nuxt, you've probably installed @nuxtjs/auth-next .
Instead of this npm install @nuxtjs/auth . My nuxt.config.js is like that. Btw I'm using laravel api with jwt authentication

```
modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "meta.token"
          },
          user: {
            url: "user",
            method: "get",
            propertyName: "data"
          },
          logout: {
            url: "logout"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

my login.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          email: '',
          password: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async submit() {
        await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
          data: this.form
        })

        this.$router.push({
          path: this.$route.query.redirect || "/"
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```